# How do you get response code when using Custom Object instead of Httpresponse

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

When I use

```
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = addHeader(.......) ~> sendReceive ~>       unmarshal[HttpResponse]
```

then I can get the Status code as it an object of HttpResponse using

```
val futureResponse = pipeline(Post(url, body)) futureResponse.map(_.status)
```

However, when I use a custom unmarshaller as:

```
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[MyResponse] = addHeader(.......) ~> sendReceive ~>      unmarshal[MyResponse]
```

using

```
val myfutureResponse = pipeline(Post(url, body))
myutureResponse.map(_.status)
```

doesn't compile as it cannot find status. How do I get the status code here? I need to use a custom unmarshaller to be able to deserialize my json result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an answer based on your suggestion

```
private def unmarshal[T: Unmarshaller](response: HttpResponse): T = {
response.entity.as[T] match {
  case Right(value) => value
  case Left(error)  ⇒ throw new PipelineException(error.toString)
}
```

}

I changed my pipeline method to be

```
val pipeline: HttpRequest => HttpResponse = addHeader(.......) ~> sendReceive
val searchResponse = pipeline(Post(urlwithpath, queryString)).map {
  response => response.status match {
    case StatusCodes.OK =>
      Some(unmarshal[MyResponse](response))
    case StatusCodes.NotFound => print(StatusCodes.NotFound)
   }
}
```

Now that I have got this out of the way, I will learn the API properly

Answer (score 1):

If you hardcode the un-marshaller in the pipeline there is no way you can get the status code. You will still get failures code as they will be part of the exception that will cause the `Future` to fail.

If you really want to keep that information AND use an un-marshaller in your pipeline you will need to write your own un-marshaller that can provide you with a response of this sort:

```
case class Wrapper[T](response: T, status: StatusCode)

val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[Wrapper[MyResponse]] = addHeader(.......) ~> sendReceive ~> myUnmarshall[MyResponse]
```

This could get quite tricky if you don't know the spray internals. Another option is to not hardcode the `unmarshall` bit in your pipeline and de-serialise the JSON manually.

Comment: Ok, cool. Thanks for the pointer, making a request to get the body and then making another request to get the code is a No No I supposed. Funny thing is I wasn't aware I was hardcoding values inside the unmarshaller. I was only following examples I found of the internet.

Comment: What I meant is that you are hardcoding the unmarshaller as part of your pipeline. You can have a look at how it is implemented and implement your if you want to have a different behaviour.

Comment: Still not 100 percent clear on the proposed solution. There aint lots of examples on the internet unfortunately. One of the solutions I saw online was to have a method that could capture the httpresonse and put in the pipeline before unmarshalling eg 'code'def mapStatus: HttpResponse => HttpResponse = { 
      case r@ HttpResponse(status, entity, _, _) => 
        r.withEntity(entity.map((ct, buf) => ContentType.`application/json` -> buf)) 
      case x => x } val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[Wrapper[MyResponse]] = addHeader(..) ~> sendReceive ~>mapStatus ~> myUnmarshall[MyResponse]

Comment: The example above extracts the entity into the HttpResponse object , and then put in the pipeline, but I am not able to do the same for status